# Angular directive for generating directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a screen in my app which should show a list of components. Now, components can be different, showing different HTML content and with varying behaviour.

So, what I need is to do an *ngRepeat*, pass an object in each iteration, and according to some param in this object generate different directive.

This is the code that I had in mind - in the view:

```
<component ng-repeat="data in dataSet" config="data"></component>
```

Directive itself:

```
myApp.directive('component', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            template: function(el, attrs) {
                switch(attrs.config.type) {
                    case 'numeric':
                        return '<numeric config="data">this is numeric</numeric>';
                    case 'bar':
                        return '<another config="data"></another>';
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

Most of this is actually working, but the issue here that I couldn't get to fix is that the directive which is generated through template does not see the value of the *config* attribute. In other words, I want to pass the object from component to the directive inside, but that's not working.

One more approach I tried but ended up having the same issues is:

```
myApp.directive('component', function($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                link: function(scope, el, attrs) {
                var newElement;
                switch(scope.config.type) {
                    case 'numeric':
                        newElement = $compile("<numeric config='data'>this is numeric</numeric>")(scope);
                        break;
                    case 'bar':
                        newElement = $compile("<another config='data'></another>")(scope);
                        break;
                }

                el.append( newElement );
            }
            };
        });
```

Another thing here is that some of the generated directives will be the ones I pulled online, so ideally my solution should not involve modifying these.

I'm open to other approaches.